# use freopen() and scanf() to read an int from file

Tags: c, file-io, stdio, freopen

I try to read an int from a file using freopen(). File *in.txt* simply have a number:1, but what I get in output is -858993460. My code is shown below:

```
#include <cstdio>
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    freopen("in.txt", "r", stdin);
    int t;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    printf("%d\n", t);
    return 0;
}
```

Why does scanf() not read from *in.txt* correctly?

Answer (score 0):

rule #1, if you have file io then check the return values

```
int main()
{
    FILE * ret = freopen("in.txt", "r", stdin);
    if(ret == NULL){
       printf("failed to open file");
       return -1;
    }
    int t;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    printf("%d\n", t);
    return 0;
}
```

your code runs fine for me once I point it at a real file

also check the return from scanf

```
 int count = scanf("%d", &t); 
 if(count != 1){
     printf("bad number");
     return -1;
 }
```

Comment: freopen return value is not NULL, but scanf return 0.

Comment: @uesr12314 thats because you have non numeric data in your file then, I have just "42" and it works fine

Comment: but the file "in.txt" definitely have numeric data "1", I also tried to change to other numbers, but the result remain the same

Comment: @uesr12314 my bet is that you are not reading the file you think you are. because you r code definitely works with the correct file. Change the name of the file with "1" in it and see what happens (don't change the code). Or change `scanf` to `fgets;printf` so you see whats there

Comment: I find the reason, I used UTF16-LE character set originally, when I change the Encoding to UTF-8, everything works well